# Jquery popup in table not showing up

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I probably have a stupid error somewhere, but I am learning.

I have a table that is dynamicly loaded from DB and each row has it's own ID
Now in that table I have this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn preview" data-id="'.$var['id'].'">
<i class="fa fa-eye"></button>
```

then in script tags lower I have this

```
$(document).ready(function() {           

           $('#pop_up').dialog({
            title: "Title",
            resizable: true,
            autoOpen:false,
            modal: true,
            width:"350px",
            height:"350px",
            buttons: {
               text:"Close",
               click: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                                           }}
         });
         $('#table_id').on('click', '.preview', function() {
               var uid = $(this).attr('data-id');
               $('#pop_up').load("filename.php?uid="+uid, function(){
                   $('#pop_up').dialog('open');
               });
         });

   });
```

there is one other button in the same td as this button. And when I click on this one nothing happens, but if I this button a few times in succession quickly the other one opens. That is not the behavior I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was my problem. I had my js in the wrong file and that file was not loaded in the view where I was clicking the button. Silly mistake.